# Create Magento module using database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to create simple module using database, but I cannot find my wrong and I don`t know how to find it( and the way to debug)
my files structure is:
MyNameSpace
-SkipCart
 --controllers
   ---IndexController.php
 --etc
   ---config.xml
 --Helper
   ---Data.php
 --Model
   ---Mysql4
      ----SkipCart
         ------Collection.php
      ----SkipCart.php
   ---SkipCart.php
 --sql
   ---SkipCart_setup
      ----mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

The code in files are:

IndexController.php

```
class MyNameSpace_SkipCart_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
     public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        //create a text block with the name of "example-block"
        $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
        ->setText('<h1>This is a text block</h1>');

        $this->_addContent($block);
  //add menu active
        $this->_setActiveMenu('tutorial_menu/first_page');
       // $this->_setActiveMenu('system/another_menu_from_us');
        $this->renderLayout();


    }


}
```

config.xml

```
<config>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNameSpace_SkipCart</module>
                    <frontName>skipcart</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
    </admin>
     <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <tutorial_menu translate="title" module="skipcart">
                <title>Skip Cart</title> 
                <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <first_page module="skipcart">
                        <title>Our First Page</title> 
                        <action>skipcart/index/index</action>
                    </first_page>
                </children>
            </tutorial_menu>
        </menu> 
         <system>
                <children>
                    <another_menu_from_us>
                        <title>Here Too!</title> 
                        <action>skipcart/index/index</action>
                    </another_menu_from_us>
                </children>
            </system>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <skipcart>
                <class>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Helper</class>
            </skipcart>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Block_Cart</cart>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>



     <global>
        <models>
            <skipcart>
                <class>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mynamespace_skipcart_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </skipcart>
            <skipcart_mysql4>
                <class>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <skipcart>
                        <table>skipcart</table>
                    </skipcart>
                </entities>
            </skipcart_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <skipcart_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyNameSpace_SkipCart</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </skipcart_setup>
            <skipcart_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </skipcart_write>
            <skipcart_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </skipcart_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <skipcart>
                <class>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Block</class>
            </skipcart>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <skipcart>
                <class>MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Helper</class>
            </skipcart>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Data.php

```
class MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

--Model
   ---Mysql4
  ---SkipCart.php

```
class MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Model_SkipCart extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('skipcart/skipcart');
    }
}
```

--Model
   ---Mysql4
      ----SkipCart
         -----Collection.php

```
 class MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Model_Mysql4_SkipCart_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {

        $this->_init('SkipCart/skipcart');
    }
}
```

--Model
   ---Mysql4
      ----SkipCart
      ----SkipCart.php

```
    class MyNameSpace_SkipCart_Model_Mysql4_SkipCart extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
    {
        public function _construct()
        {   
            $this->_init('skipcart/skipcart', 'skipcart_id');
        }
    }
```

--sql
   ---SkipCart_setup
      ----mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
    <?php

    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->run("

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('skipcart')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('skipcart')} (
      `skipcart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`skipcart_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        ");

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Can anybody help me and find the problem, and may be explain me how to find and debug the error alone?

Comment: At first glance, the only thing I see is in Collection.php: $this->_init('SkipCart/skipcart');  skipcart should be lowercase. Other than that, what happens when you try to use the module? Try logging through the module, and look in the error logs.

Comment: I fixed the file collection.php but no effect. I don`t know what you mean with ' Try logging through the module'? I just logged in admin panel and then I checked in database for the new table.

Comment: By logging, I mean use the built-in log/debug function to find out where it stops. Use Mage::log() in different places in your php code to mark what is happening, then watch var/log/system.log to see what gets written and what doesn't.

Comment: I tried to put Mage::log('works'); in the all files, but I have a result in system.xml when I put the code only in IndexController.php. I tested it like I refresh admin panel. I think that just the extention doesn`t read the Modul folder but I don`t know why!? The config.xml looks good. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what's not working, since you haven't described what you're trying to do and where it's failing. From what I can tell, at no time do you actually get it to call any of your Models, either through a rewrite or a dispatchEvent. Your XML says to rewrite the Block_Cart, but you don't actually have a Block folder.

Comment: Аctually I have a Block which rewrite Block_Cart. In the same time I am trying to create a form in admin panel which can disable my SkipCart Block and in the same time to add some information in database from this form. I don`t call any of my Models but for now I first trying to create the table. Next step will be to fill this table.